# Python importing module from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I want to import the module from another directory **scripts/driver/scheduler.py** to **run.py** and execute it, but every time I get the following error msg

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'

I added empty **init**.py files, but it didn't solve the issue

Here are a tree and the code:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── pythonmodules
│   ├── module
│   │   └── run.py
│   └── setup
│       └── smthelse
└── scripts
    ├── driver
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── scheduler.py
    └── resources
        └── smthelse
```

run.py

```
import argparse
import os.path as op
from scripts.driver.scheduler import scheduler

some lines of code
s = scheduler()
```

scheduler.py

```
import re
import sys

class scheduler():
    some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = scheduler()
```

Could somebody explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: from which directory are you runnning run.py

Comment: from the main directory of the project by the following command:

python3 pythonmodules/module/run.py

Comment: I think you need to add the **init.py** to `scripts`. Followed by using `sys.path.insert(0,absolutepath)` before `from scripts.driver.scheduler import scheduler`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow pythonpath was missing. The following export fixed it:
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user/myapp